# Pagination on grouped / multi sorted lists

Tags: lists, sorting

I'm currently working on a design for data heavy lists. User research showed, that users would group / multi sort those lists. this would result in a list with small header rows in between for every sort parameter.

So far so good. I'm now having a hard time, as those lists have a pagination. I would now also need to show the grouped rows over all pages which might take the user out of context...

any thoughts on how to solve the problem?

The sort order here is: Dev. Status -> Section -> Manager

[image]

Comment: Can you add some wireframes or examples?

Comment: For sure - find it up there :)

Answer (score 2):

I’ve recently seen beautiful replacement for regular pagination: “Load more” button at the end of the page. It fetch next portion of data and put it right after existing list so it seems like more list data is revealed.

Beautiful part is that you don’t need to go back and forth to see data that is divided between page 1 and page 2. You just see it as a one list - scroll up / down.

To be able to navigate the list you still may like to add pagination, presented as vertical line at the right side of the list. For user it will work similar to “scroll to”, although technically you will do the same as unloading actual list and loading it’s data located on selected page (does this make sense?)